# IOS, how to clear context graphics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cgcontextdrawpdfpage

In my app I have a method that draws a pdf into a context:

```
 CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, index + 1);

 CGAffineTransform transform = aspectFit(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFTrimBox),
                                                          CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));

 CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);

 CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page);
```

Now in drawLayer, that is called when zooming, I do the necessary transformations and call again `CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page);`

What happens is that a zoomed pdf is drawn on top of the first pdf, the problem is that in a particular page with only text, the back and blurred pdf is shown. That is strange, I thought that pdf page had white background and if this happens it's because the zoomed pdf on top has transparent background.

Now, to solve this how can I clear the context right before the CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page) of drawLayer method? I tried:

```
//self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

//CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
//CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);

//CGContextClearRect(ctx, layer.bounds);
```

Nothing works...thanks in advance

Comment: Your question suggests that the first context is not the same context as you use in `drawLayer:`. How do you create the original ctx, when do you draw into it, and what are you doing with it afterwards?

Answer (score 13):

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to flush the context as below?

```
CGContextFlush(ctx);
```